# RxJava Retrofit and mockito test doesnt work

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit

i dont know why, but for a specific route, its not working:

Desired route:

```
@POST("v2/current-time")
fun utc_time_from_server(): Observable<Response<Void>>
```

my test:

```
    @Test
    fun test_call_request_time_success_on_first_header_response() {

//        given
        var mockedResponse = Any()
        var millis = 1L


        server.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .addHeader("millis", millis)
                .setResponseCode(200)
                .setBody(""))

//        when
        doReturn(sharedPrefs).`when`(application).getSharedPreferences(any(), any())
        doReturn(Observable.just(mockedResponse)).`when`(api).utc_time_from_server()
        presenter.requestTimeSyncPeriodic()
        testScheduler.triggerActions()


//        then
        val calls = Mockito.inOrder(view, database, unbiasedClock)
        calls.verify(unbiasedClock).saveServerTime(1L, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), application)

    }
```

my presenter method called requestTimeSyncPeriodic (the method is called every one minute from mainActivity timer, only one for testing purpouse)

```
  fun chainTimeRequests(): Observable<Long> {
        return apiBag.apiMirror1.utc_time_from_server()
                .flatMap { response -> if (response.isSuccessful && response.headers().get("millis") != null) { return@flatMap Observable.just(response) } else { return@flatMap  apiBag.apiMirror2.utc_time_from_server() } }
                .flatMap { response -> if (response.isSuccessful && response.headers().get("millis") != null) { return@flatMap Observable.just(response) } else { return@flatMap  apiBag.apiMainFast.utc_time_from_server() } }
                .flatMap { response -> if (response.isSuccessful && response.headers().get("millis") != null) { return@flatMap Observable.just(response.headers().get("millis")!!.toLong()) } else { throw TimeMillisOnHeaderNullException("") } }
    }

    fun requestTimeSyncPeriodic() {
                disposable.add(
                        chainTimeRequests()
                                .subscribeOn(scheduler.ui())
                                .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
                                .subscribe(
                                        { utcMillis ->
                                            unbiasedClock.saveServerTime(time = utcMillis, elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), application = application) },
                                        { error ->
                                            error.printStackTrace()
                                            view?.doNothing()
                                        }

                                )
                )
    }
```

i dont know why its giving this results:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to retrofit2.Response
```

but if change the test mock api call return to any other route nothing related

like:

```
doReturn(Observable.just(mockedResponse)).`when`(api).call_any_other_route()
    presenter.requestTimeSyncPeriodic()
```

the test pass correctly, i really cant understand why for utc_time_from_server it cant work,

`abr 18, 2018 4:24:27 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[35751] starting to accept connections
abr 18, 2018 4:24:30 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[35751] received request: POST /v2/current-time HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

Comment: i think my error is that im not using the mock server response, im using the doReturn response =|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was using doReturn response (mocking the mocked response and expecting the first mocked as result hahahah, confusing? yep)